# Octave GUI Command window flashes after being resized to a bigger size

Tags: windows-7, octave

I am running octave 4.0.2 on windows 7 64 bit vm hosted on a mac with El Capitan in Parallels Desktop.

I have a Thunderbolt display with the resolution 2560x1440.

When I make the main Octave GUI window bigger than a certain size, the command window starts to flash and it displays all sorts of garbage characters. I attached a screenshot I took while the command window was flashing. It seems that a threshold for the command window is approximately 1320x965 including scrollbars, i.e. when the command window becomes bigger, it starts flashing garbage characters. The window is sensitive to increasing either the width or height. Also, if the width is smaller, it will start flashing a higher height.

Any ideas on how to fix this and what might cause it?

Thank you

Update: I posted this: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47893

[image]

Comment: I suggest contacting the developer...

Comment: @excaza: I submitted a bug and I included the link in my post.

Comment: If you run GNU Octave in a VM I suggest using GNU/Linux as OS (Debian/Ubuntu for example) and not windoze.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, thank you for the suggestion. I have a Centos VM. I am going to install it there.

Comment: Worth noting, to get it to stop blinking just downsize the window again. (I know you might know this already, posting it for others sake)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a bug in the software: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45220.